# Can we find our C++ code in a signed APK?

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

Can we find our C++ code in a signed APK by profiling it by using Android Studio profiler? If we can find then what is the path of that file in the .apk file.

How the Android Studio package a C++ file while building signed apk of an app?

Comment: what do you mean `C++ file`?

Comment: Your C++ code will be compiled into processor specific assembly before injected into the APK. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to find out if anyone can access out C++ code from .apk file by decompiling it.

Comment: They can't get to your source code, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Do you have any documentation link regarding it?

Comment: @shizhen C++ file means a file in which C++ code is written.

Comment: @UserSharma - If you understood how the APK and C++ build process works, you wouldn't be needing documentation.  You do realize that the APK file is jus a ZIP file?  Go rename your APK to have a `.zip` filename extension and unzip it with your favorite tools.  You won't see the C++ source code.  Binaries of compiled code don't include their own source.

Comment: your apk is an archive of **compiled source and resource files**, you won't be able to find any plain source files.

Comment: c++ source code is not stored. It is compiled into low-level commands

Comment: Your C++ code is compiled into machine code for some target architecture and ABI (e.g. armeabi-v7a), and packaged into `.so` files (dynamic libraries). The original source code is not included in those libraries or anywhere else in your APK. However, if you build a debug version of your native library then it might contain something that almost looks like your original C++ source code, because it is useful for debugging purposes. But I'm assuming that you're not releasing debug builds of your app publically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can we find our C++ code in a signed APK by profiling it by using Android Studio profiler?

No. The [Android Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler) is used to gather data on CPU, memory and network usage.

You could use the [APK Analyzer](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer) to view information about your APK, but even that won't show you the source code of your C++, and if it's a properly compiled APK it wouldn't even show you the source code of your Java either.

> How the Android Studio package a C++ file while building signed apk of an app?

A C++ source file is compiled as [native code](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code), in this way, a system library is built that is then linked against in your Java project via [JNI](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni).

That being said, if one was so inclined, there is nothing stopping them from grabbing your APK, analyzing it, finding the specific libraries that are not Java byte code, decompile them in some tool like IDA or just running it through a debugger/disassembler and reverse engineering your code to figure it out themselves (this is how we have emulators for video game consoles after all), but that takes *a lot* of time.